# Angular 2 CustomReqeuestOptions merge() not working since Angular 2 RC.5

Tags: angular

I had a CustomRequestOptions class to wrap all http requests within base API URL.
the class looks like this:

```
import {BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers} from '@angular/http';

export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

     merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.url = 'http://127.0.0.1/api/public/' + options.url;
    if (options.method === 1) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    options.headers = headers;
         }
    return super.merge(options);
  }

}
```

When my app is running and trying to execute the following code:

```
loadData()
    {
        this.http.get('data')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {           
     console.log("TEST");
      );
    }
```

I get this error:

```
browser_adapter.ts:82 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: newOptions.merge is not a function
```

Why merge is not working anymore and what's the alternative?

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    {provide:RequestOptions,useValue:CustomRequestOptions},
```

Comment: How do you use `CustomRequestOptions`?

Comment: in my app,module.ts `providers: [
    {provide:RequestOptions,useValue:CustomRequestOptions},`

Answer (score 1):

You should provide your custom request options with useClass instead of useValue as below:

```
providers: [
   { provide:RequestOptions, useClass:CustomRequestOptions }
]
```

There is a nice [blog post](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) about dependency injection from Pascal Precth.